# How to use setter option (get; set; ) for IList Properties in Realm Model?

Tags: c#, .net, realm, realm-list

I have a model class that is extended from the realm object. In some cases, I use this model as both realm model and POST operations. Currently, the realm IList properties unable to support setter options. Is there any option or way to achieve this?

Here is my current code:

```
[JsonObject]
public class Product : RealmObject, IProduct
{
   [MapTo("name")]
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MapTo("skuDetails")]
    [JsonProperty("skuDetails")]
    public IList<SkuDetail> SkuDetails { get; }
}
```

My requirement :

```
[JsonObject]
public class Product : RealmObject, IProduct
{
   [MapTo("name")]
    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MapTo("skuDetails")]
    [JsonProperty("skuDetails")]
    public IList<SkuDetail> SkuDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to derive your class according your need. 
this is totally possible like the code below:

```
public interface ITest
{
    IList<object> SkuDetails { get; }
}

public class OutTest : ITest
{
    public IList<object> SkuDetails { get; set; }
}
```

Please note that extending property method is supported however opposite of it is not.

Ex: 
    public interface ITest
    {
        IList SkuDetails { get; set; }
    }

```
public class OutTest : ITest
{
    public IList<object> SkuDetails { get; }
}
```

is not possible.